# PL/ SQL- WHEN / Conditional commands

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to increase the salary of three employees by prompting the user. The job_ids are 1, 4, and 8. I cannot seem to get my WHEN statements to work or properly interact with the datatables. Anyone have any insights?

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
    SET VERIFY OFF

    accept selection prompt 'Please enter your employee ID'

    DECLARE

    JobNumber INT(2) := ('&selection.');

    NewSalary VARCHAR2(30);

   BEGIN

    update emp_employee
    set NewSalary = case
        WHEN JobNumber = '1' THEN NewSalary := emp_employees.salary * 1.10;
        WHEN JobNumber = '4' THEN NewSalary := emp_employees.salary * 1.15;
        WHEN JobNumber = '8' THEN NewSalary := emp_employees.salary * 1.20;
        ELSE 'Invalid ID'
        END;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Job ID '|| JobNumber || 'Salary ' || NewSalary);

  END;

  /
```

Comment: The assignments (`NewSalary := `) and the semicolons (`;`) after the factors are no valid syntax. Also the string type in the `ELSE` branch doesn't match the numeric type of the other branches. And you are aware, that you update **every** row in the table as you `UPDATE` without a `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 0):

i think your update should be like below

```
   update emp_employee
        set NewSalary = case
            WHEN JobNumber = 1 THEN  emp_employees.salary * 1.10;
            WHEN JobNumber = 4 THEN  emp_employees.salary * 1.15;
            WHEN JobNumber = 8 THEN emp_employees.salary * 1.20;
            ELSE null
            END;
```

//`NewSalary`  is numeric field you can not assign string value `invalid`

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide test case, I'm using Scott's schema and his EMP table. The principle is the same, though.

Have a look a this example and note the differences:

- `CASE` you wrote is wrong; you've already said that NewSalary should be *something* (within the `UPDATE`), so you don't repeat it once again)
- `ELSE` can't be 'Invalid ID'; you'd put a string into a `NUMBER` datatype column. I handled it within the `IF` statement - if nothing has been updated, such an employee doesn't exist.
- you can't *output* NewSalary as you don't know it. I *returned* its value into a separate local variable (l_new_sal)

Also, if I were you, I'd rather create a *stored procedure* instead of using an anonymous PL/SQL block. If you use it for educational purposes, let it be (but you can try to convert it to a procedure, if you want).

Here you go; one example with a non-existent `EMPNO`, and another one for employee that exists.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> set ver off
SQL> accept par_selection prompt 'Enter EMPNO: '
Enter EMPNO: 1234
SQL> declare
  2    l_empno   emp.empno%type := &par_selection;  -- it is employee ID, not job number!
  3    l_new_sal emp.sal%type;
  4    l_cnt     number;
  5  begin
  6    update emp e set
  7      e.sal = case when e.deptno = 10 then e.sal * 1.1
  8                   when e.deptno = 20 then e.sal * 1.15
  9                   when e.deptno = 30 then e.sal * 1.2
 10                   else e.sal
 11              end
 12      where e.empno = l_empno
 13      returning sal into l_new_sal;
 14
 15    l_cnt := sql%rowcount;
 16
 17    if l_cnt > 0 then
 18       dbms_output.put_line('Employee ' || l_empno || ', new salary = ' || l_new_sal);
 19    else
 20       dbms_output.put_line('Nobody got new salary');
 21    end if;
 22  end;
 23  /
Nobody got new salary

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> accept par_selection prompt 'Enter EMPNO: '
Enter EMPNO: 7369
SQL> /
Employee 7369, new salary = 920

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Hey Littlefoot! Thank you so much for your help on this question. With your sample I was able to modify your code and get the output I was looking for! Thanks again I'm new to the PL/SQL version and some of this syntax is a little new for me.